# Decompiled APK, Catlog "ClassNotFound" Errors

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Hi I'm attempting to revamp an app for my Xiaomi Yi camera so it will push a notification when the camera battery is low. The app has everything in there to do it, just doesn't have that feature I'm needing. So I've used APKStudio to decompile and imported into eclipse, but I'm getting a bunch of ClassNotFound errors.

I assume it's because the lib actually consists of .smali instead .class. But I'm not 100% certain.

Here's the catlog:

```
02-04 13:16:47.426: I/art(2347): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-04 13:16:47.435: W/System(2347): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera-1/lib/x86
02-04 13:16:47.435: D/AndroidRuntime(2347): Shutting down VM
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347): Process: com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera, PID: 2347
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     ... 9 more
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraApplication
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):         ... 12 more
02-04 13:16:47.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2347):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

It doesn't look there is any anti-decompile like ProGuard or anything.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera" platformBuildVersionCode="22" platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.market.sdk.UPDATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.permission.AUTH_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.channel.GAME_SERVICE_PERMISSION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraApplication" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="veengine_version" android:value="5"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LogoSplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LocalPicEditActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/PicEditStyle"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraVideoSplendidActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsHomeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LandscapeCameraControlActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsPhotoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsViewPhotoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsVideoActivity"/>
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraConnectionFailedActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraQuickRecordShareActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.QuickRecordEditActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.DownloadPhotoShowActivity" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraMediaShowActivity" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.PhotoSetDetailShowActivity" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LocalVideoPuzzleActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraFileDownLoadActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraSettingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraSDCardActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/SDCardSettingTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraWifiSettingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraUpgradeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraUpgradeWaittingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraUpgradeSuccessActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraUpgradeFailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.FirmwareDownloadActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SettingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.VideoCropActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.VideoEditActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LocalMediaShowActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsWebViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.SnsVideoMoreActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.FeedbackActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.moments.NotificationListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MomentsTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.moments.EditPersonalActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MomentsTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.moments.ReportLowersActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MomentsTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraUpgradeHelpActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraHelpActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.FaqActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:label="@string/xiaomi_login" android:name="com.xiaomi.account.openauth.AuthorizeActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="cn.sharesdk.framework.ShareSDKUIShell" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="tencent100371282"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mob.tools.MobUIShell" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="tencent100371282"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="com.xiaomi.xy.sportscamera.wxapi.WXEntryForXiaoyiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.LocalVideoEditActivity"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.ants360.z13.recevier.CheckFirmwareUpgradeRecevier">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
                <action android:name="camera.intent.action.cancel.firmware.download"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.ants360.z13.recevier.DownloadCompleteRecevier">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.DetailGridViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.activity.CameraVideoEditActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.AccountActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.CommunityMessageActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.CommunityDetailActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.CommunityThemeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.AccountSettingActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.ReportOrShareActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.TestActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CameraTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ants360.z13.community.FullScreenImageActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/FullImage"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"/>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/global_tracker"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/application_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The root file structure:

```
src <-- empty
gen
Android 5.1.1
assets
bin
lib
original
res
smali
unknown <-- just contains unimportant "mistats_version" text file
AndroidManifest.xml
project.properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new feature to the app, you will have to learn **SMALI**, it's not possible to full convert **APK** to **JAVA**.  I have never used APKStudio, but I can recommend you **dex2jar** or **APKtool**, on [THIS](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/) website you can find commends how to decode and build APP again.

Comment: Hmm trying that way but simply decoding and building without making changes, it spits out "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]" in the emulator

Comment: EDIT: happens for original apk as well. I suppose it's an issue with the emulator setup

Comment: Well I thought it worked after setting up a new virtual device with ARM, but I guess I tested with the original apk twice. I was using teamviewer on my phone and probably forgot. Anyway, it's throwing [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION] even though I made no changes and rebuilt directly after decompiling.

Used "apktool d test.apk" to decompile and "apktool b -c test" to recompile using the original certs/sign.

Comment: Last update: Using APKStudio again and this time correctly set up the signing portion and everything is working. No idea why the -c flag wasn't working for apktool.